# Caption to follow cursor in Royalslider plugin

Tags: javascript, css, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to achieve this but I can't make it work: I'm using the Royalslider WP gallery plugin and I want the Caption of each image to automatically follow/replace the cursor, like here: https://www.martonperlaki.com/#1 
And also at the same time if the user clicks anywhere, the next slide loads, but this function is already enabled via the options of the plugin (navigate by click).

I'm using the Scripts n Styles plugin to add this JS to the specific page in which the gallery is located, but just nothing happens and I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var xPos = e.pageX;
  var yPos = e.pageY;
  // console.log(xPos, yPos);
  $('.rsGCaption').css({
    'top': yPos,
    'left': xPos
  });
});
```

And this is the css for the caption class.

```
.rsDefault .rsGCaption {
float: left;
text-align: center;
z-index: 90;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid blue;
color: black;
width: 45px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

I appreciate your help!
Thank you